# Error of 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'items' when training a MIL model

Tags: neural-network, google-colaboratory, tensor, mnist, multiple-instances

I'm trying to use the MIL (Multiple Instance Learning) in Speech Processing Area. I have implemented the code which is published by Lori Sheng in github line by line using Google Colab environment. I took an error at the last section namely "In [60]". Can you please help me about this error? I'm trying to find solution for nearly two weeks but no solution because I'am newbie. I tried to explained the error in detail below.

Source code link is: https://github.com/lsheng23/Practicum/blob/master/MIL_MNIST/end_to_end_mnist_MIL.ipynb

In [60], "outputs = model(X)" calls the "forward" method of "MIL_NN" class which is In [58].

Then it throws that kind of error;

```
 89         figure out batches
 90         """
 91         bag_feature, bag_att, bag_keys = list(zip(*[list(self.agg(ff.float())) + [idx] for idx, ff in (bag_features.items())]))
 92  AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I thought it is maybe because of sth like "tf eager execution" but I realized that it was not.

I also applied the author's note which is  n=7*512, but still no solution.

Also before this error, I needed to make some corrections (even I'm not sure if it is right) in author's code because of "file not found/ file does not exist" errors. These were;

In [39] from "feature_array.npy" to "feature_array_full.npy" and In [40] from "feature_t_array.npy" to "feature_test_array_full.npy"

Thanks in advance for your valuable helps.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `torch.tensor` does not have a method called `items()`. Use `item()` (singular) instead to get the raw number, however, with a python `dict` you can use `.items()`. Both are different.

In the example you provided, `bag_features` is a `dict`, but from the error you posted you are calling `.items()` on a tensor. Try printing `type(bag_features)` and see what it is returning.